# VS2017 repeatedly appends GlobalSection to solution file

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2017, ankhsvn

VS2017 v15.9.3, every time I open the solution file, it marks the solution file has changed. When I view changes, I saw the same guid gets appended again and again. Is this a VS bug or AnkhSVN bug?

```
Global
    GlobalSection(SubversionScc) = preSolution
        Svn-Managed = True
        Manager = AnkhSVN - Subversion Support for Visual Studio
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
        SolutionGuid = {guid}
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
        SolutionGuid = {same guid gets repeated}
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

Comment: Hey, M facing the issue with VS 2019, how did you manage to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem it would always append a:

```
GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
    SolutionGuid = {same guid gets repeated}
EndGlobalSection
```

In my case I had this part missing

```
GlobalSection(SubversionScc) = preSolution
        Svn-Managed = True
        Manager = AnkhSVN - Subversion Support for Visual Studio
EndGlobalSection
```

But even after adding it, it still repeatedly added the GlobalSection above.

What I noticed was that if I double clicked on the solution file from file explorer to open it, it didn't add it but opening by selecting from the latest solution files from visual studio it did.

Now the silly solution which seemed to have some influence for some reason:

*I removed the solution from the latest solutions opened from visual studio, so it had to add it again.*

I haven't had the problem since I did this for some reason.

Thought I'd mention it in case it helps somebody else.