# GlobalSection ExtensibilityGlobals is repeated in .sln file

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, solution, ankhsvn

I checked almost all questions w.r.t this on stack overflow, but didn't find appropriate answer.

In my project solution file I can see a repeated entry for `GlobalSection` with `SolutionGuid`, as follows:

```
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
        SolutionGuid = {E3949C94-3551-44F7-BE8B-1FFE4A668402}
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SubversionScc) = preSolution
        Svn-Managed = True
        Manager = AnkhSVN2019 - Subversion Support for Visual Studio
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
        SolutionGuid = {E3949C94-3551-44F7-BE8B-1FFE4A668402}
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
        SolutionGuid = {E3949C94-3551-44F7-BE8B-1FFE4A668402}
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
        SolutionGuid = {E3949C94-3551-44F7-BE8B-1FFE4A668402}
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
        SolutionGuid = {E3949C94-3551-44F7-BE8B-1FFE4A668402}
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
        SolutionGuid = {E3949C94-3551-44F7-BE8B-1FFE4A668402}
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
        SolutionGuid = {E3949C94-3551-44F7-BE8B-1FFE4A668402}
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

Every time when I open solution in VS2019 creates a new entry of GlobalSection. This should not happen usually a .sln file should have only one section for `SolutionGuid`. Due to this modification in .sln file, source control detects this as a change and we have to commit or revert it every time.

As you can see `GlobalSection` for `SolutionGuid` entry is repeated 7 times with the same GUID. why? How to fix this or this is a bug?

Comment: Which specific problem do you have with this solution?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski GlobalSection (ExtensibilityGlobals) for SolutionGuid gets added every time when I open the solution. This should not happen, due to this our source control detect this as a change in .sln file.

Comment: ExtensibilityGlobals is meant to allow add-ins to store data in the .sln file.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56759432/vs2017-repeatedly-appends-globalsection-to-solution-file) and [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/228623/solution-file-on-network-drive-grows-each-time-whe.html) are more victims, you almost surely need to file a bug with AnkhSVN.

Comment: @HansPassant oh!! I thought its bug from VS2019. If its from AnkhSVN, i doubt if its well maintained and active.